# BEM hierarchy in stylus-lang and namespace

Tags: namespaces, stylus

Consider this html (written with BEM aproach):

```
<div class="app app--light">
  <div class="longblockname longblockname--modifier">
    <div class="longblockname__element">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to find convenient and short stylus stylesheet for this and avoid repeating `longblockname` everywhere. I'll replace the real styles with simple `color: #111`, but in real case there're a lot of code:

I start with:

```
.longblockname
  &__element
    color #111
```

Then I want the block modifier to affect on the element:

```
.longblockname
  &__element
    color #111
  &--modifier
    // How to refer to &__element here?
    // If I use &__element, it will compile to `.longblockname--modifier__element`
    // But I need `.longblockname--modifier .longblockname__element`
```

I see 2 ways to achieve this:

Do not use line break:

```
.longblockname
  &__element
    color #111
  &--modifier &__element
    color #222
```

This will work, but if we want to use nested feature of stylus, is there any way to avoid ugly `^[-1]` syntax like that:

```
.longblockname
  &__element
    color #111
  &--modifier
    & ^[-1]
      &__element
        color #222
```

Well, ok, probably that's just syntax preference, but for me it would be much nicer to have something like `&&` to refer to the nested parent.

Then, there's the real question. Is there any way to declare css namespace in stylus? The whole application wrapped with the container that has `app app--light` style. I want this style to affect on everything within the container. I start with putting everything inside the .app-light:

```
.app--light
  .longblockname
    &__element
      color #333
    &--modifier
      & ^[-1]__element
        color #444
```

But this will not work because `& ^[-1]__element` compiles into `.app-light .longblockname--modifier .app--light .longblockname__element` while the correct syntax should be `.app--light .longblockname--modifier .longblockname__element`. I want `.app--light` to prepend any style declaration, but only the first time. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I removed [sass] and [less] tags because SO is about concrete questions/answers (so you'd better to avoid things like "I'm interested in a Stylus solution, but I also would not mind more info on all possible options in all other languages").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with [Ranges in partial references](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/selectors.html#ranges-in-partial-references) to get only the selectors in the tree you want:

**Stylus**

```
.app--light
  & .longblockname
    &__element
      color #333
    &--modifier
      & ^[1..1]__element
        color #444
```

**Output**

```
.app--light .longblockname__element {
  color: #333;
}
.app--light .longblockname--modifier .longblockname__element {
  color: #444;
}
```

Comment: I accepted your answer because it solves this particular case, but I'm looking for something more usable. The real case is that you already have some styles, there might be several `&` references in one line as well as ^[-1] constructions and so on. It's huge, but some styles overwritten by the framework because the last does not use bem approach. The goal is to increase the strength of your layout - add one `.app--light` class to the wrapper and wrap the whole stylus with one rule that will prepend once every rule with `.app--light`.